# Unknown property: 'color-adjust'

Tags: html, css

```css
[multiple] {
  background-image: initial;
  background-position: initial;
  background-repeat: unset;
  background-size: initial;
  padding-right: 0.75rem;
  -webkit-print-color-adjust: unset;
  color-adjust: unset;
  print-color-adjust: unset;
}
```

Unknown property: 'color-adjust'

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: what would be the question?color-adjust is not a valid css property

Comment: https://caniuse.com/css-color-adjust

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use -webkit-print-color-adjust and print-color-adjust.
But color-adjust is not a valid css property.

```css
[multiple] {
  background-image: initial;
  background-position: initial;
  background-repeat: unset;
  background-size: initial;
  padding-right: 0.75rem;
  -webkit-print-color-adjust: unset;
  print-color-adjust: unset;
}
```